# Issues on loading the database library with CodeIgniter 2.1.3

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am using CodeIgniter, and i want to add a functionality in someone else's project by accessing the database.
When i automatically load the database library in the autoload.php file this way,

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('doctrine','session','form_validation','database');
```

have an error starting like this

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_pconnect()

How can I fix that ?

Answer (score 1):

> **Change dbdriver to MySQLi**

Path `application/config/database.php`

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = '';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli'; # Change this
```